# React & Node.js fetch basic authorization

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I am using fetch api to make request from reactjs to node.js backend with Basic Authorization with the code below...

**React**

```
fetch(baseUrl, {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    authorization: 'Basic ' + secret,
  },
}).then((res) => {
  if (res.ok) {
    return res.json();
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
  }
})
  .then((resBody) => {
    //
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

**Node.js**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  return next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {

  const base64Credentials = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';

  const [username, password] = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString().split(':');

  const auth = { username: 'username', password: '123456' }
  console.log(username, password, auth.username, auth.password);
  // comment below
  if (username === auth.username && password === auth.password) {
    return next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Authentication required.'); // custom message
  }

});
```

The following error is occur when I try to make the request.

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

However, when I comment the comparison part in the second middleware **if (username === auth.username && password === auth.password)** it works fine. I have tried using Postman to send request it also no problem happen. The problem only occur when I make the request from react app. Anyone know what is the reason? Thanks a lot

Comment: do you use the CORD npm?

Comment: I didn't use cors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that  the CORS npm is no installed   `npm i cors` and write this code:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
```

[more information about CORS npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)